# Having trouble panning and zooming on my d3 map

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have this map in d3

```
http://107.170.20.64/
```

that renders topojson with a custom projection and path, like this

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator().translate([width / 2, height / 2]).scale(width * 185).center([-89.99, 29.975]);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

I am trying to adapt it so that it pans and zooms using Bostock's [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2374239). Here is the function that fires once the topojson loads (showing my adaptations of Bostock's method):

```
   function ready(error, us) {
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .translate([0, 0])
            .scale(1)
            .scaleExtent([1, 8])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        var features = svg.append("g");

        features.append("g")
            .attr("class", "precincts")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.orleansgeojson).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", (function(d) {
                return wards.get(d.id) + " precinct";
            }))
            .attr("title", (function(d) {
                return votesone.get(d.id) + "-" + votestwo.get(d.id);
            }))
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d.id;
            })
            .attr("d", path);

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(zoom);

        function zoomed() {
            features.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            features.select(".precinct").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
        }
```

Somehow, zoomed is never getting called. If I set a breakpoint on zoomed it never catches. I think that the final append to svg calls zoom which somehow sets up a [d3 behavior](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior) that creates listeners for mouse events and calls the zoomed function. That's what I understand so far about what is going on (clarification or detailed answers would be great). Is the problem that the listeners are not getting set? If so, how do I debug why they are not getting set? The overlay shows up in my svg -- it just does not seem to be picking up mouse events.

Comment: do the `call(zoom)` from the g element which is a container...the rect element is not a container. Check the [first statement](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior) in this page. Notice the call from g in this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919).

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes what do you mean by container? The features?

Comment: Yep, that should do it. Svg:g is a container but svg:rect is not...

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes no luck, unfortunately

Comment: The code you've posted here doesn't correspond to the code on your page. Have you tried the code you've posted here?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff following FernOfTheAndes' suggestion I tried moving the call to zoom to chain to both the .append calls on "g" and the append calls on svg. Neither one works, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that you're setting the `z-index` on your `#map` element to be -1. This way it won't receive any pointer events.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes that was it. I did not know that if z-index was set to -1 it would not get pointer events. If you write that as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is unrelated to the zoom behaviour. You're setting the `z-index` of the `div` containing the map to be -1. This means that it's behind the *containing `div`*, which gets all the mouse events. So the map is "obscured" by the element that contains it.

To fix, either set the `z-index` of the map `div` to be higher than -1, or set the `z-index` of all the containing elements (including the `body`) to be -1 or less.